# JSP Page directive formatting in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, formatting

Given a JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" %>
```

If you use Eclipse's indent (CTRL+I) or format (CTRL+SHIFT+F) functionality, you'll get this:

```
<%@ page language="java"%>
```

Notice the space character at the end has been removed. Is there any way to configure Eclipse to keep this space when using indent or format?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can define the tag to be formatted (Inline elements is useful), but it's always dangerous to use CTRL+SHIFT+F in a JSP.

1) Eclipse => Window => Preferences => Web => HTML Files => Editor

If you can install a plugin you can always try with [Eclipse WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/), with it JSP formatting can be customized under:

2) Eclipse => Window => Preferences => Web => JSP Files => Editor

Comment: I agree with this: "it's always dangerous to use CTRL+SHIFT+F in a JSP", definitely been my experience so far. Can you elaborate on the "Inline elements" bit? That looks like a finite list to me, which won't work for the JSP page directive as it's not a standard HTML tag.

Comment: It doesn't work strictly for JSP page directive but removing "input" from inline elements is always useful for formatting the page.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but not especially relevant for my problem.

Comment: Well, base Eclipse doesn't have much for JSP formatting, I'm suggesting you a plugin in the answer.

Comment: I already have the WTP plugins, it doesn't seem to add much extra functionality in terms of formatting to be honest.